# How to keep group of elements on the same page

Tags: page-breaking

I have a custom heading with dynamic content. My content is composed with tabulars, itemize and paragraphs. I am using the environment (`samepage`) with severals `\nopagebreak` in each part of the content to ensure that the content between two `\nopagebreak` will be on a new page or at least will stay together on two pages.

The content is correctly seperated. The problem is the header of the whole content doesn't follow the start of the content. The header stays in page 2 and the content starts at page 3.
Here's the code that I use for the header.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{217,217,217}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=1.5in,right=0.75in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\begin{samepage}
\nopagebreak
\begin{snugshade*}{\fontsize{13}{6}\selectfont\textbf{Testing}}\end{snugshade*}
\nopagebreak
\lipsum[4]
\nopagebreak
\lipsum[5]
\nopagebreak
\lipsum[6]
\end{samepage}

\end{document}
```

I saw that there's the minipage and needspace that I can use for undestructible blocks but the problem is that I have dynamic content so I do not know the lenght of it.
I also try to put `\nopagebreak` after or before the header but it doesn't work.

My header and the dynamic content are inside one `samepage` block.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please, explain what `snugshade*` is.

Comment: `snugshade` makes a colored rectangle under the text. `snugshade*` is the same except that the left margin is aligned with the text below. The `snugshade` is aligned to the document margin.

Comment: What's the package providing it? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I have edited my 1st post to include some random text.

Comment: I have put an answer that can replicate the `snugshade*` that would do the work I want.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen in the `snugshade` documentation ([here](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/framed/framed.pdf)) that it is using a `colorbox` with a defined color named shadecolor. When i use the colorbox in the code provided, the content are correctly seperated. So i have tried to recreate the snugshade with a tabular like this :

```
\colorbox{shadecolor}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
\fontsize{13}{6}\selectfont\textbf{Testing}
\end{tabular}}\\
```